# Падает приложение на Android ниже 6 версии

Tags: android, permissions

Приложение не работало с файлами на внешнем носителе под Android 6. После того как поразвлекался с runtime permissions и добавил в основном активити проверку, отлично заработало на 6й версии но перестало работать в версиях ниже. При старте приложения: "В приложении произошла ошибка". Что интересно что на эмуляторах проблем нет и под 5й версией, а на двух реальных устройствах 5 версии падает.

Попробовал закомментировать функции проверки но эффект остался =(

В чем может быть проблема? Понимаю что вопрос не конкретный, но не знаю даже с чего начать.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

[Ссылка на проект](https://github.com/Zets-swe/Calculator)

Код правда специфический и криворукий.

Comment: а запустить под отладкой на реальном устройстве - какая ошибка?

Comment: Начать надо со списка permissions, targetSdkVersion и примеров кода.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja
Отладку по usb не пробовал. Сейчас попробую освоить. 

Список добавил в вопрос. Пример кода - не знаю какую часть привести, поэтому добавил в вопрос ссылку на проект. Пробовал закомментировать все разрешения тоже не помогает.

Comment: @plesser Запустив из Android Studio на телефоне через USB (если это имелось ввиду под отладкой) все заработало без проблем =(

Comment: То есть проблема ушла?

Comment: @plesser Да, но только если приложение установлено через Android Studio. Может я не правильно поступаю при обычной установке? Я беру файл app-debug.apk из \app\build\outputs\apk. До этого проблем не возникало.